# Where is the error in my calculation for a simple bosonic system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, second-quantization, bosons

$ \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right\rangle} 
$I was doing some calculations and I came across something that confused me and maybe you can explain to me where my reasoning is wrong. Let's say I have some bosonic systems described by the tensor product of four independent states:
$$ \ket{\psi} = \ket{n_1} \otimes \ket{n_2} \otimes \ket{n_3} \otimes \ket{n_3} \tag{1}\label{1}$$
The vacuum state is of course
$$ \ket{\varnothing} = \ket{0} \otimes \ket{0} \otimes \ket{0} \otimes \ket{0} \tag{2}\label{2}$$
Let's define some composite operator
$$ \hat{A}=\sum_i \hat{a}_i \tag{3}\label{3}$$
where $\hat{a}_i$ is the annihilation operator for the $i$-th state of the tensor product. The action of the adjunct of the operator $(\ref{3})$ onto the vacuum state $(\ref{2})$ is
$$ \begin{align}
\hat{A}^\dagger\ket{\varnothing}&= \ket{1} \otimes \ket{0} \otimes \ket{0} \otimes \ket{0} \\
&\quad+\ket{0} \otimes \ket{1} \otimes \ket{0} \otimes \ket{0} \\
&\quad+\ket{0} \otimes \ket{0} \otimes \ket{1} \otimes \ket{0} \\
&\quad+\ket{0} \otimes \ket{0} \otimes \ket{0} \otimes \ket{1} \tag{4a}\label{4a}\\
&=\ket{\psi} \otimes \ket{\psi} \otimes \ket{\psi} \otimes \ket{\psi} \tag{4b}\label{4b}
\end{align}$$
where
$$ \ket{\psi} = \ket{1} + 3\ket{0} \tag{5}$$
Now, repeating this identical for the operator $(\ref{3})$ as written results in
$$ \begin{align}
\hat{A}\ket{\varnothing}&= 0 \otimes \ket{0} \otimes \ket{0} \otimes \ket{0} \\
&\quad+\ket{0} \otimes 0 \otimes \ket{0} \otimes \ket{0} \\
&\quad+\ket{0} \otimes \ket{0} \otimes 0 \otimes \ket{0} \\
&\quad+\ket{0} \otimes \ket{0} \otimes \ket{0} \otimes 0 \tag{6a}\label{6a}\\
&=\ket{\psi} \otimes \ket{\psi} \otimes \ket{\psi} \otimes \ket{\psi} \tag{6b}\label{6b}
\end{align}$$
where
$$ \ket{\psi} = 3\ket{0} \tag{7}$$
which is obviously not correct, since the result should be the zero-vector. Where is my mistake? Is the step from $(\ref{4a})$ to $(\ref{4b})$ actually allowed? Clearly, for $(\ref{6a})$ to $(\ref{6b})$ this cannot be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each term in eq. (6a) is multiplied by zero (not the $\vert 0 \rangle$ vector, but the number zero). Therefore the whole is identically zero (the number again).

I also do not agree with result (4b). The fourfold tensor product of the given $\vert \psi \rangle$ (5) contains a term $\vert 1,1,1,1 \rangle$ which is clearly absent from (4a).

Comment: After thinking about it more closely, there seems to be no way to simplify the sum.